# mysql date interval, php date interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dateinterval

I have students table and they must pay every month, I have `start_day` and `end_day`.

For example:

```
start_day = "2018-01-01";

end_day = "2018-03-30";
```

I want to send an SMS 3 days before pay day. I don't know how to fetch those dates in this interval.

Comment: Pay date is your end date ?

Comment: @GauravKandpal - *must pay every month*

Comment: no. during start_day and end_day they will in course . they must pay every month after start_day

Comment: try "WHERE `start_day` = DATE(NOW() , INTERVAL 3 DAY)"

Comment: find diffrence day between start and end using this `$diff=date_diff($start_day,$end_day);`  and then use condition `if $diff == 3`  then send sms.

Comment: What exactly do you want to select? All payment dates in the interval? All payment dates in the interval after today? The next payment date after today? The last payment date before today? A flag indicating whether today is a payment day?

Comment: payment day start from start_day to the end_day , every month

Comment: @KainMikayilli Why don't you run cron job every day and fetch all students whose start_date is greater than current date and end_date is smaller. Then check if todays date is the 3 day before end of the month with this $smsday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-t') . ' -3 day')). If it is, send the sms.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id from schema.table where end_day between
subdate(current_date, interval 3 day) and subdate(current_date, interval 2 day);
```

A bad way to do this would be : `where date(end_day) = current_date-3`

Why I don't prefer the bad way (although it looks simple):

1. Avoid using functions on `joins` and `where` clause. This'll prevent indexes (if any) from being used and will give you nightmares in terms of performance.
2. Use only the correct operators with intended datatype. `-` is an arithmetic operator. It's generally not a good practice to use `+/-` with dates. Use the functions intended to manipulate dates. (`subdate, date_add, date_sub` etc)